# Custom color for ICellStyle FillForegroundColor than provided named colors

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, npoi

We are newly started using NPOI components.

We are having issues to set FillForegroundColor of ICellStyle property.

```
ICellStyle HeaderCellStyle = xssfworkbook.CreateCellStyle(); 

HeaderCellStyle.FillForegroundColor = NPOI.HSSF.Util.HSSFColor.RED.index;
```

FillForegroundColor expects of type short.

How do we set a different color rather than using colors in HSSFColor.

We need to set to `"RGB192:0:0"` and how do we do that for ICellStyle property FillForegroundColor

Colud someone help us by some example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the solution my self. Please refer below code

```
byte[] rgb = new byte[3] { 192, 0, 0 };
 XSSFCellStyle HeaderCellStyle1 = (XSSFCellStyle)xssfworkbook.CreateCellStyle();
 HeaderCellStyle1.SetFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(rgb));
```

Comment: Casting my style to `XSSFCellStyle` was all I was missing.

Comment: I'm sorry to downvote but this is not answering the question. Your question is about `ICellStyle` but you only answer for the `XSSFCellStyle` class. This doesn't work with the other `HSSFCellStyle` class which is also inheriting `ICellStyle`

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL HSSF only understands a color index into a palette. Your options appear to be either search the workbook palette for something close, or replace an existing palette entry with your custom color.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, and again.

```
Color SuperColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 0, 0);
styleH.FillForegroundColor = GetXLColour(hssfworkbook, SuperColor);


private short GetXLColour(HSSFWorkbook workbook, System.Drawing.Color SystemColour)
{
    short s = 0;
    HSSFPalette XlPalette = workbook.GetCustomPalette();
    NPOI.HSSF.Util.HSSFColor XlColour = XlPalette.FindColor(SystemColour.R, SystemColour.G, SystemColour.B);
    if (XlColour == null)
    {
        if (NPOI.HSSF.Record.PaletteRecord.STANDARD_PALETTE_SIZE < 255)
        {
            if (NPOI.HSSF.Record.PaletteRecord.STANDARD_PALETTE_SIZE < 64)
            {
                NPOI.HSSF.Record.PaletteRecord.STANDARD_PALETTE_SIZE = 64;
                NPOI.HSSF.Record.PaletteRecord.STANDARD_PALETTE_SIZE += 1;
                XlColour = XlPalette.AddColor(SystemColour.R, SystemColour.G, SystemColour.B);
            }
            else
            {
                XlColour = XlPalette.FindSimilarColor(SystemColour.R, SystemColour.G, SystemColour.B);
            }

            s = XlColour.GetIndex();
        }

    }
    else
        s = XlColour.GetIndex();

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a solution for XSSFWorkbooks?

Comment: This "solution" looks nice at first glance and inspires, but you are trying to overwrite a const value: ```NPOI.HSSF.Record.PaletteRecord.STANDARD_PALETTE_SIZE```. Also a little explaination about how the palette is limited would help a lot. ```FindColor()``` and ```FindSimiliarColor()``` is the real help here. That said, this is almost answering the question (other answers using XSSF or no custom RGB color are not as fitting as this one).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a VB equivalent answer, I had to convert this, so maybe it will save someone some work if they find it:

```
'my workbook is from a template that already contains some header data
Dim fs As New FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("..\_ExcelTemplates\filename.xlsx"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)            
Dim workbook As IWorkbook
workbook = New XSSFWorkbook(fs) 
Dim sheet_stats As ISheet = workbook.GetSheet("Stats")

'style
Dim rgb_grandTotalRow_fg() As Byte = New Byte() {197, 217, 241} 'lightish blue
Dim style_grandTotalRow As XSSFCellStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle()
style_grandTotalRow.SetFillForegroundColor(New XSSFColor(rgb_grandTotalRow_fg)) 'XSSFCellStyle only for other use (FillForegroundColor = IndexedColors.LightTurquoise.Index)
style_grandTotalRow.FillPattern = FillPattern.SolidForeground

'apply the style to a cell
Dim rowHdr As IRow = sheet_stats.GetRow(2)
Dim cell As ICell

cell = Row.CreateCell(1) 'create cell at col index 1
cell.CellStyle = style_grandTotalRow
cell.SetCellValue("TEST")
```

Answer (score 1):

change font color

example..

```
ICellStyle style0 = hssfworkbook.CreateCellStyle();

IFont font0 = hssfworkbook.CreateFont();
font0.Color = NPOI.HSSF.Util.HSSFColor.RED.index;
style0.SetFont(font0);

for (int i = 0; i < cell.Length; i++)
{
    cell[i].CellStyle = style0;
}
```

--

I'm Japanese, can't English. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

For people coming here in 2016, you can find lots of useful colours here:

```
nameStyle.Color = NPOI.HSSF.Util.HSSFColor.BlueGrey.Index;
```

Whereby BlueGrey is the colour you are looking for.