# NPOI: Set cell color to a custom color

Tags: c#, apache-poi, npoi

How do you set the cell color to a custom color using C# NPOI?
I know how to change the the color of a cell with NPOI using the color index:

```
XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
cellStyle.FillBackgroundColor = IndexedColors.LightCornflowerBlue.Index;
cellStyle.FillForegroundColor = IndexedColors.LightCornflowerBlue.Index;
cellStyle.FillPattern = FillPattern.SolidForeground;
ICell cell = CurrentRow.CreateCell(CellIndex);
cell.CellStyle = cellStyle;
```

However, I want to use a custom color. The IndexedColors are limited and not that useful.
I've have looked around a long time now for an answer.

---

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687901/custom-color-for-icellstyle-fillforegroundcolor-than-provided-named-colors) from years back but it doesn't seem to be relevant any longer. SetFillForegroundColor is now a short and is no longer a XSSFColor.

```
byte[] rgb = new byte[3] { 192, 0, 0 };
XSSFCellStyle HeaderCellStyle1 = (XSSFCellStyle)xssfworkbook.CreateCellStyle();
HeaderCellStyle1.SetFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(rgb));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have been using FillBackgroundXSSFColor and not FillBackgroundColor

```
XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
byte[] rgb = new byte[3] { 255, 221, 221 };
XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(rgb);
cellStyle.FillBackgroundXSSFColor = color;
ICell cell = CurrentRow.CreateCell(CellIndex);
cell.CellStyle = cellStyle;
```

Comment: Cells would show all black with this exact approach for me, using NPOI 2.6.1.
However, changing `cellStyle.FillBackgroundXSSFColor = color;` to `cellStyle.SetFillForegroundXSSFColor(color);` did the trick